# Jupyter for Scala with spylon-kernel without having to install Spark

Tags: scala, jupyter-notebook

Based on web search and as highly recommended, I am trying to run Jupyter on my local for Scala (using `spylon-kernel`).

I was able to create a notebook but while trying to run/play a Scala code snippet, I see this message *initializing scala interpreter* and in the console, I see this error:

```
ValueError: Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation).
```

I am not planning to install Spark. Is there a way I can still use Jupyter for Scala without installing Spark?

I am new to Jupyter and the ecosystem. Pardon me for the amateur question.

Thanks

Comment: Zeppelin supports this, not sure about Jupyter.

Comment: How about https://almond.sh/ ?